# PHP week1 and week2 system

Tags: php, date, timetable

Im trying to create a timetable in PHP. My timetable goes through a Week 1 and a Week 2. Week 1 comes straight after week 2 and week 2 comes straight after week 1, this repeats each week.

How can I use PHP to find which week I am in from a date?

Comment: What is yout table structure, what gave you tried si far?

Comment: Honestly im at an odds on what to try at all. Im using JSON to store the periods and there rooms/lecturers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`W` is the week number of year.

```
function whatMyWeek($timestamp) {
    if ((int) date('W', $timestamp) % 2) {
        return 'week odd'; // Week 1 
    } else {
        return 'week even'; // Week 2
    }
}

// now
echo whatMyWeek(time()); // week odd

// a week ago
echo whatMyWeek(time() - 60*60*24*7); // week even

// two week ago
echo whatMyWeek(time() - 60*60*24*7*2); // week odd
```